# Debugging in protractor

Tags: angularjs, node.js, debugging, testing, protractor

I find myself in a completely different scope using `browser.debugger()`. I cannot access the other scope variables from my tests, only global variables. Here is the backtrace:

```
debug> bt
#0 protractor.js:1039:5
#1 webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ promise.js:1598:20
#2 webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ promise.js:1463:8
#3 b native v8natives.js:1594:37
```

Am I supposed to debug using `browser` and selectors only?

Answer (score 1):

actually, when i debug protractor spec.js, i do use node-inspector,

1. install node-inspector from command line
   'npm install -g node-inspector'
2. use below command to begin debug
   'node-debug node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor test/protractor-conf.js'

then chrome window should open, and pause at the first line of protractor, from sources / file:// part find your *spec.js, add breakpoint in *spec.js, run, chrome should pause at you just setted breakpoint
,do not need to use browser.debugger() or debugger;

Answer (score 0):

We're using the chrome driver with Intellij and we're able to set break points right in the IDE.  We add the line broswer.debugger(); and then we put a break point after it.
We had issues getting debugging to work.  We got it working on 2.40 I believe. Check the git history to see if anything has changed with the version you're using.
Good luck

Comment: do you mean that you put a ```debugger;``` statement right after the ```browser.debugger()``` line?